# How to get an Azure AD access token from Azure Application proxy pre-authentication

Tags: azure

I'm using an Azure application proxy to connect with all internal applications with pre-authentication. All these applications are legacy .NET applications. We are now developing a .NET Core API application to make use of MS Graph APIs. To access the MS Graph API we need an access token of the logged-in user with pre-authentication.

Answer (score 1):

yes you get access token easily try this this is Microsoft login in this you have received access token easily. first of all you need to create a app in Azure Protal [Azure Portal][1] creating new app you need to give Redirect URI Select platform Web and in your project you need to create a new .html file for Redirect URI. you can give localhost like this [https://localhost:44326/Redirect.html] and register app in your app overview you will receive {Application (client) ID ,Directory (tenant) ID,}. Now click on {Token configuration} in Token configuration page click on Add optional claim and select token type Access and Add. In Api permission you can add if you need. after all things now you need to use it. Use this code in your js file

```
let dialog;
function login() {
    let a = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=Add your client id here without any space &response_type=token&redirect_uri= your redirect_uri &scope=user.read%20mail.readwrite%20mail.send&response_mode=fragment&state=12345&nonce=678910";
    //let a = "https://localhost:44397/Redirect.html";

    // mailboxItem.body.getAsync("html", { asyncContext: event }, checkBodyOnlyOnSendCallBack);
    // Declare dialog as global for use in later functions.
    Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(a, { height: 30, width: 20 },
        function (asyncResult) {
            dialog = asyncResult.value;
            dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, processMessage);
        }
    );
}
function processMessage(arg) {
    dialog.close();
    let messageFromDialog = JSON.parse(arg.message);
    console.log("accessToken", messageFromDialog)
  //  window.localStorage.setItem("accessToken", messageFromDialog)
}
```

Add this code in your Redirect.html file

```
<script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>


        var address_Link = window.location.href;
        console.log(address_Link)
        var address_arr = address_Link.split("=");
        var address_Token = address_arr[1];
        var Id_Token = address_Token.split("&");
        var access_token = Id_Token[0];
        console.log(Id_Token)

        Office.onReady(function (appInfo) {
            Office.context.ui.messageParent(JSON.stringify(access_token));

</script>
```

I loin url add your client id and your redirect_uri.
when login successfully you will receive Access Token in your js.
hopefully it is helpful for you I tried my best to explain you.